# Debugging jest tests with vue.js and vscode

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, jestjs

I'm using vscode 1.69.2 and when I set a break point in a vue file and try to debug a jest test, I get the breakpoint showing up in this compiled code, and not in my source code.  In the linked image the break point opens in an identical file name as the Source EventSummary.vue file.

This is I think is the relevant section of my package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.18.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-rc.17",
    "@vue/vue3-jest": "^27.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.18.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.1.1",
    "markdownlint-cli": "^0.31.1",
    "mocked-env": "^1.3.5",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ],
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/tests/env.js"
    ],
    "preset": "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/tests/css-stub.js",
      "d3": "<rootDir>/node_modules/d3/dist/d3.min.js"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "vue"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.vue$": "@vue/vue3-jest"
    }
```

Launch.json

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "name": "vscode-jest-tests.v2",
      "request": "launch",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "disableOptimisticBPs": true,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "args": [
        "test",
        "--",
        "--runInBand",
        "--watchAll=false",
        "--testNamePattern",
        "${jest.testNamePattern}",
        "--runTestsByPath",
        "${jest.testFile}"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[vscode example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coCRu.jpg)

Comment: any luck with this? having same issue :(

Comment: Nope, still a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the jest.config.js -

```
transform: {
  '^.+\\.vue$': 'vue-jest',
  '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
 },
```

Then create/update your launch.json with the following -

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
  {
    "name": "jest-tests",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "runtimeArgs": [
      "--inspect-brk",
      "./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js",
      "test:unit",
      "--runInBand"
    ],
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",    
    "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
    "outFiles": [ "${workspaceFolder}/src/**/*.js"]
  },
]
```

Now from VSCode debug tab select this jest-tests and start debugging.